# How to get count of subjects taken by each student?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I've two models 'Students' and 'Enrollments'.

The schema for these is as below:

```
class Students(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField()

class Enrollments(models.Model):
    enroll_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Students, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subjects = models.charField()
```

I'm trying to achieve the result of following SQL query in Django Rest Framework, for getting number of subjects enrolled by students (individually).

```
select
    s.id, s.name, count(e.subjects) as count
from Students as s
left outer join Enrollments as e
    on e.student_id_id = s.id
group by s.id, s.name, e.subjects
order by count asc;
```

This query returns result like:

```
---------------------------
|  id  |  name  |  count  |
---------------------------
|  1   |  a     |  1      |
|  2   |  b     |  0      |
|  3   |  c     |  2      |
---------------------------
```

Can anyone please help me acheive this kind of result.

Note: I need 0 count students details also.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is when you are creating a serializer, you can add a serializer method field which will get the count for you.

Add this at the top of your serializer:

```
count = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_count')
```

Then add a function inside your serializer like this:

```
def get_count(self, obj):
    try:
        return Enrollments.objects.filter(student_id=obj.id).count()
    except:
        return None
```

Finally, add 'count' to your field list. You can then add as many fields as you want. I hope this will get you your desired result. Also don't forget to use "select_related" in the ORM inside your view to reduce the amount of queries.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But, can you give me complete view with this serializer implementation.

Comment: @lazoman btw the try/except block isn't needed, `.count()` return zero if the queryset is empty